# Cannot load excel file - The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssms

I've created an SSIS package that loads an Excel file to an SSMS with no problems.

When I deploy the package to SSMS and run the package from there I get this error:

> Error: the requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

I've tried absolutely everything to fix this.

I've downloaded the 32-bit `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` and changed the SSIS package to run in 32-bit mode and also changed it in SSMS to run in 32-bit mode.

Just to be sure I also tried all of this but with 64 bit versions... still getting the same error...

My Excel, SSMS and Visual Studio are all 32-bit. When looking at my system through Control Panel > System, my system type is 64-bit.

Is there any way at all I can get this working through SSMS? I've exhausted the internet for solutions. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please post the version of your: Visual Studio, SSMS, SQL Server, OS, Office

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider for Both 64-bit and 32-bit using the \passive command? https://datasavvy.me/2017/07/20/installing-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-for-both-64-bit-and-32-bit-processing/

Comment: Have you tried to run the package in 32 bit mode? Click on the solution => properties =? Debugging => Set run in 64 bit to false.

Comment: Have you tried to change SQL Agent job to run in 32-bit runtime? Go to SQL Job > right click properties > step > edit(step) > Execution option tab > Use 32 bit runtime

Comment: All fixed thanks guys, as well as running the package and job in 32 bit i had to download AccessDatabaseEngine onto the server as well as the machine! Thanks !

Comment: Post it as the right solution